# XSL Most common

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I'm new to XSL and I'm trying to create an XSL stylesheet to print the name of the most common author based on the number of articles they have written, as specified in an XML document.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="busiestAuthor.xsl"?>
<latestIssue>
<issue number="357" />
<date>
    <day> 4 </day>
    <month> 1 </month>
    <year> 2013 </year>
</date>

<stories>
    <story>
        <title> The earth is flat </title>
        <author> Tom Friedman </author>
        <url> http://www.HotStuff.ie/stories/story133456.xml </url>
    </story>

    <story>
        <title> Films to watch out for in 2013 </title>
        <author> Brated Film Critic </author>
        <url> http://www.HotStuff.ie/stories/story133457.xml </url>
    </story>

    <story>
        <title> The state of the economy </title>
        <author> Tom Friedman </author>
        <url> http://www.HotStuff.ie/stories/story133458.xml </url>
    </story>

    <story>
        <title> Will an asteroid strike earth this year? </title>
        <author> Stargazer </author>
        <url> http://www.HotStuff.ie/stories/story133459.xml </url>
    </story>
</stories>
</latestIssue>
```

So the result I want busiestAuthor.xsl to print is just **Tom Friedman**, as he has written 2 articles and everyone else has only written one. I'm sure it's probably pretty easy but as I say I'm new to all this and I can't seem to manage it. Between for-each loops and sorts and counts my head is spinning.

Appreciate it guys, I'm studying in college and a question like this is tipped to come up in some shape or form for my final exams. Cheers!

Comment: Can you update your question with what you have tried, what processor you use and what version of XSLT you are using? Otherwise, for the basic idea you will want to look up the Muenchian method for XSLT 1.0 and for-each-group for XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most useful strategy here is probably to

1. define a *key* giving you all the stories for a given author name
2. sort the list of authors in descending order of the number of matches for its key value
3. take just the first element of this list

The key definition goes outside all your templates:

```
<xsl:key name="storiesByAuthor" match="story" use="author" />
```

Then to sort by number of stories and take the first element, you'd need to do something like this in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/latestIssue/stories/story/author">
  <xsl:sort select="count(key('storiesByAuthor', .))"
            data-type="number" order="descending" />
  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
    <!-- in here, . is one of the author elements for the author with the
         most stories -->
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The fact that this for-each produces repeats is not a problem here, as you only care about the first "iteration".  If you have more than one author with the same maximum number of stories you'll get whichever one is mentioned first in the original document (as `xsl:sort` is "stable", i.e. items with the same sort key value are returned in document order).

For XSLT 2.0 you could use `xsl:perform-sort` instead of a `for-each`, but given you're using `<?xml-stylesheet?>` I presume you're doing the transformation in a browser, and most (all?) browsers only support 1.0.

Comment: +1 Also in XSLT 2.0, the OP could use `distinct-values()`. I think you're right about 1.0 though (`<?xml-stylesheet?>`).